# Sublime tries to compile Python-script as a Haskell-script

Tags: python, haskell, sublimetext

I am newbie, pls don't be to harsh with me.

I am trying to setup Sublime Text with Python (for next Semester). Before that I used Haskell in SublimeText, where I could run my skript with "ctrl+b" in Sublime.

When I try doing the same with a file named "test.py".

```
  def add(a,b):

      return a+b

  main = print(add(2,3))
```

I get the error-message:

```
/home/nayooti/Desktop/test.py:1:1:
    **Parse error: naked expression at top level**
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: runhaskell "/home/nayooti/Desktop/test.py"]
[dir: /home/nayooti/Desktop]
[path: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games]
```

The "naked expression at top level"-part looks familiar, since it is very Haskell specific. Indeed, when I search the Web for exactly this message, it brings me to Haskell related stuff only. So apparently Sublime or the compiler thinks, I am trying to run a Haskell-script, even though I named the file ~.py .

For these, who are not familiar with Haskell and Python:
you can usually run a script by:
Python: main = print(method(x,y))
Haskell: main = print(function x y)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. What am I doing wrong here? Help is very appreciated. Tx.

Comment: Tx. I've been there, but it's not. I know about Ctrl+B and when I use it, I get the error message I posted above.

Comment: Have you set the build system?

Comment: As said, I am newbie, and I am not exactly sure what 'set built system' means. I guess Ubuntu comes with Python, and I am able tu execute via console. I haven't set any path in Sublime, in case that was your question.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Tools -> Build System` and make sure that `Python` is selected.  Also, that is not how you write main in Python, it should be more like

```py
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def main():
    print(add(2, 3))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When you write

```py
main = print(add(2, 3))
```

And load your script, that line gets executed since it is an assignment, much the same if I did

```py
a = 1
```

Or

```py
a = print(add(2, 3))
```

There is nothing special about the name `main` in Python.  You still see your output because `print` has side effects, but rather than defining `main` you are just executing a script.  The difference comes in if you were to try

`add.py`:

```py
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

main = print(add(2, 3))
```

`subtract.py`:

```py
from add import add

def subtract(a, b):
    return add(a, -b)
```

If you ran `python subtract.py`, you would still see `5` printed to the screen, even though there is no `main` defined in `subtract.py`.  Obviously, this is not desired behavior, your `main` function in `add.py` should not be executing if you did not run it as the main script.  When you run a Python script directly as `python scriptname.py`, there is a variable set global to that file called `__name__` that gets assigned the string `"__main__"`.  If you import it, then `__name__` is set to its qualified module name, something like `"scriptname"`.  This gives you the ability to define different behavior if the file is executed compared to if the file is imported by another script.